# codeigniter site, swfobject not fully loading swf

Tags: codeigniter, flash, loading, swfobject

I am having a strange problem.  I have a view that is supposed to load a swf.   The swf was compiled with Flex and the mxml preloader displays but it loads a blank screen.  When I path directly to the file it loads fully and works fine.

Other possibly relevant information:
The swf makes calls through GET requests to the database
the site is built with codeigniter
I'm using swfobject to load the swf

you can see it in all it's busted glory here:
http://thetoad.flattoads.com:16080/~iopdev/CI/index.php?c=moodtotem&m=index

I'm going bonkers over this!

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you need an "embed" tag? See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp).

The JS solution [swfobject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/) might reduce the pain of having to do cross-browser stuff yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug SWF with Flex.

Perhaps something with sandbox restriction or wrong paths in the SWF? If you load the SWF directly, all seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  You're right MysticEarth, there was a problem with the swf trying to locate resources, it was looking for the folder in the site root for some reason. We were able to locate the problem with the LiveHTTPHeaders plugin for firefox.
Thanks!